# how to decrement number by 2 for loop in php

Tags: php, for-loop

The following is a simplified version of my code:

```
for($n10 = 10; $n10 = 1; $n10--2{
    echo $n10;
};
```

I want the number in the second paragraph to increment by 2 with each loop, e.g.

```
10, 8, 6, 4
```

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: `for($i = 10; $i >= 0; $i -= 2) echo $i;`

Comment: Homework questions should show prior work http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Comment: @Sky: I see no indication that OP is asking for homework help. It's a simple question, but let's not jump to conclusions. He did show his work; he posted a non-working attempt.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The last component can be seen like a block of code, so you can do the following...

```
for($index=10;$index > 0;$index-=2) {
    echo $index;
}
```

The `-=` is equivalent to `$index = $index - 2`